# same background color for all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I want to make the customer choose a color and then when he go to other page, the color stay the same. this is the code for the choosing color on the first page:

```
       <select id="color" style="width: 5%; height: 10%" size="5">
       <option value="white">White</option>
       <option value="red">Red</option>
       <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
       <option value="blue">Blue</option>
       <option value="green">Green</option>
   </select>
   <script>

       document.getElementById("color").onchange = function () {
           document.body.style.background = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
       }
```

Comment: You'd have to use a server side language or cookie.

Comment: Look into using cookies or server side sessions.

Comment: Just append it to the new url, and have your js parse the url.

Comment: Answered your question :) Tell me if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.localStorage):

```
document.querySelector('#color').addEventListener('change', function () {
  document.body.style.background = this.value;
  localStorage.setItem('appColor', this.value);
});

document.body.style.background= localStorage.getItem('appColor');
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr1od4d1/).  Each time you choose a color, it's remembered and will be the default color the next time you run it.

Side note: You can simplify this:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
```

… to this:

```
this.value;
```

Comment: Thanks it's work , and if I have a multiple pages and I want to apply the chosen color on the other pages. How can I do it?

Comment: On each page, add this line:  `document.body.style.background= localStorage.getItem('appColor');`

Answer (score 0):

This should be your script:

```
<body onload="OnLoad()"> //onLoad: run the function OnLoad() when the body is being load
    <select id="color" style="width: 5%; height: 10%" size="5">
       <option value="white">White</option>
       <option value="red">Red</option>
       <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
       <option value="blue">Blue</option>
       <option value="green">Green</option>
   </select>

   <script>
    function OnLoad() {
        document.getElementById("color").onchange = function () { //Getting the background color from the select
            document.body.style.background = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; //Setting the background color
            document.cookie="WebBackgroundColor=" + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; //Storing in a cookie named: WebBackgroundColor the color that was chosen
        }
        var color = getCookie("WebBackgroundColor"); //Getting the color stored on the cookie
        document.body.style.background = color; //Setting the background color to the same color as stored in the cookie
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

To add this script to other pages you need to change the body from: `<body>` to `<body onload="OnLoad()">`

and you need to add all the script thing at the bottom of the page (or the header part):

```
   <script>
    function OnLoad() {
        document.getElementById("color").onchange = function () { //Getting the background color from the select
            document.body.style.background = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; //Setting the background color
            document.cookie="WebBackgroundColor=" + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; //Storing in a cookie named: WebBackgroundColor the color that was chosen
        }
        var color = getCookie("WebBackgroundColor"); //Getting the color stored on the cookie
        document.body.style.background = color; //Setting the background color to the same color as stored in the cookie
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks it's work , and if I have a multiple pages and I want to apply the chosen color on the other pages. How can I do it?

Comment: It's work but again I wanted that the color which chosen on the first page will apply to the other pages like the answer of @Rick Hitchcock

Comment: @nirds32 mine is working like that too ;) You just need to add the lines I wrote in every page